# Android ImageButton has unequal width and height

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an 32x32 image in an ImageButton. Although layout_width and layout_height are set to wrap_content the ImageButton is shown as a rectangle with the height greater than the width. The container layout is a LinearLayout, nothing special around weighting the size of other widgets in this layout.

Why is this? It seems after I have upgraded my phone from 4.1.1. to 4.4 this strange behavior came in.

Comment: button is not by default square. so it may show some rectangle shape. try imageView

Comment: Please pos your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image fixed size. If yes means you can mention the fixed size instead of using wrap content.

Or if it's dynamic means you can use the below SquareImageview

```
public class SquareImageView  extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }
}
```

Use this class in your app.

Then call this SquareImageView instead of ImageView and the `layout_height should be match_parent`